# Create a table form from Doctrine entities

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I have a list of Doctrine entities (called "**Circuit**") and would like to generate a form listing them within a *<table>* and add a way to tick them for mass deletion (kind of what Sonata Admin does, without the need for an admin class).

I've looked everywhere but I can't figure out for the life of me what to do. There is just one layer to this class (plain old object), and every time I try to add a *collection* type to my form builder I get the following error:

> Neither the property "circuits" nor one of the methods "getCircuits()", "circuits()", "isCircuits()", "hasCircuits()", "__get()", "__call()" exist and have public access in class "NetDev\CoreBundle\Entity\Circuit".

Am I supposed to create a "proxy" class to create a collection of circuits ? Did I miss something ?

All the howtos I found so far are using a "master" class like "Article" and a collection of child classes like "Categories" which doesn't apply to my present issue.

Here is my **CircuitsController.php** (I use the "addAction" for the tests, eventually everything will be located in indexAction):

```
<?php

namespace NetDev\WebManagerBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use NetDev\CoreBundle\Form\CircuitType;
use NetDev\CoreBundle\Entity\Circuit;

class CircuitsController extends Controller {
  public function indexAction($page = 1) {
    $listCircuits = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('NetDevCoreBundle:Circuit')->findAll();
    $content = $this->get('templating')->render('NetDevWebManagerBundle:Circuits:index.html.twig',
                                                array('listCircuits' => $listCircuits));
    return new Response($content);
  }

  public function addAction(Request $request) {
    $circuit = new Circuit();
    $form = $this->createForm(new CircuitType(), $circuit);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
      /* some action that is not actually relevant */
    }
    return new Response($this->get('templating')->render('NetDevWebManagerBundle:Circuits:add.html.twig',
                                                         array('circuit' => $circuit,
                                                               'form' => $form->createView())));
  }
```

The **CircuitType.php** file:

```
<?php

namespace NetDev\CoreBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CircuitType extends AbstractType
{
    /**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     * @param array $options                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
          ->add('circuits', 'collection', array('type' => 'entity', 'allow_add' => true,
                                                'allow_delete' => true, 'by_reference' => false,
                                                'label' => false,
                                                'options' => array('class' => 'NetDevCoreBundle:Circuit',
                                                                   'label' => false, 'multiple' => true,
                                                                   'expanded' => true)
                                                ))
          /* ->add('vlanId', 'integer', array('required' => true, 'label' => 'VLAN ID')) */
          /* ->add('popOut', 'text', array('required' => true, 'label' => 'Injecting PoP', */
          /*                             'max_length' => 3)) */
          /* ->add('popsIn', 'textarea', array('required' => true, 'label' => 'Listening PoP')) */
          /* ->add('bandwidth', 'integer', array('label' => 'Bandwidth')) */
          /* ->add('xconnectId', 'text', array('label' => 'Cross-connect ID')) */
          /* ->add('Create', 'submit') */
        ;
    }

    /**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     * @return string                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'netdev_corebundle_circuit';
    }
}
```

And finally, the **Circuit.php** entity file:

```
<?php

namespace NetDev\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 * Circuit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 *                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 * @ORM\Table()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="NetDev\CoreBundle\Entity\CircuitRepository")                                                                                                                                                                   
 */
class Circuit
{
    /**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     * @var integer                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     *                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     * @ORM\Id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     */
    private $id;

    /**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     * @var integer                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     *                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     * @ORM\Column(name="vlan_id", type="integer")                                                                                                                                                                                             
     * @Assert\Type(type="int")                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     * @Assert\Range(min="1", max="4096")                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     */
    private $vlanId;

    /**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     * @var array                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     *                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     * @ORM\Column(name="pop_out", type="array")                                                                                                                                                                                               
     * @Assert\NotBlank()                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     * @Assert\Length(max=3)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
     */
    private $popOut;

    /**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     * @var array                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     *                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     * @ORM\Column(name="pops_in", type="array")                                                                                                                                                                                               
     * @Assert\NotBlank()                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     */
    private $popsIn;

    /**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     * @var integer                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     *                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     * @ORM\Column(name="bandwidth", type="integer")                                                                                                                                                                                           
     * @Assert\Type(type="int")                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     */
    private $bandwidth;

    /**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     * @var string                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     *                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     * @ORM\Column(name="xconnect_id", type="string", length=255)                                                                                                                                                                              
     * @Assert\NotBlank()                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     * @Assert\Length(max="255")                                                                                                                                                                                                               
     */
    private $xconnectId;

    /* Getters and Setters stripped for clarity's sake */

    public function __toString() {
      return "{$this->vlanId}-{$this->popOut}";
    }
}
```

If you need the twig template tell me, I haven't added it because I am not even close to having something outputted aside from that Exception.

Comment: Your "proxy" class can just be an array with a key called 'circuits' which in turn contains an array of circuit entities.  Pass the array as form data.

Comment: @Cerad indeed that works. I tried to directly use the ->findAll() result of the indexAction and oddly enough it worked too so I'll stick to it. Thanks for the help ! Post that as an answer if you want to so I can mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @Cerad, the answer here was to pass the result of

```
$listCircuits = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('NetDevCoreBundle:Circuit')->findAll();
```

directly to the collection. Everything worked nicely afterwards.